# How to access ViewModel properties within an ASP.NET MVC View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I am using the following ViewModel to create an Employee

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
   Employee employee{ get; set; }
   Budget budget { get; set; }
}
```

How can I access the properties of Employee object inside my view? I would like to do something like

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee.EmployeeID)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start by having a controller action that will pass this model to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    EmployeeViewModel model = ...
    return View(model);
}
```

then you have a corresponding view which is strongly typed to this model and in which you will be able to access the properties of this view model:

```
@model EmployeeViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.employee.EmployeeID)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```